# Dynamically updating meta tags in AngularJS single page app

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to figure out how to dynamically update meta tags in an angularjs single page application.  I have figured out how to do it for the title tag by using:

```
 myApp.run(function($location, $rootScope) {
 $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, previous) {
 $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
 });
 });
```

and

```
 <title ng-bind="title">myApp</title>
```

and

```
 $routeProvider.when('/', {
     templateUrl : '/pages/home.html',
     controller  : 'homeController',
     title: 'the home page'  
    })
```

But am stumped how to extend this to the meta tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [resolve](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) like this

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
   .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'home.html',
    controller  : 'homeController',
    resolve : {
        pageTitle : function(){
          return {'title':'Home Page Title.'}
        }    
      }
    })
});

app.controller('homeController', function($scope, pageTitle){
  $scope.title = pageTitle.title
});
```

**home.html**

```
<title ng-model="title"></title>
```

Here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EvSQDi?p=preview) but you need to